# Access Exchange Online shared mailboxes from SharePoint app

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I'm trying to solve the follwing task in a SharePoint provider hosted ASP.NET MVC app: From Exchange Online

1. find all Shared Mailboxes a user has access to and
2. list the unread emails.

For the first part MSFT suggested using the Exchange PowerShell-Commands, which is not a desirable solution, but working with a service account with full credentials.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
$sharedMailboxes = Get-Mailbox | where {$_.recipientTypeDetails -eq 'sharedmailbox' }
$mailboxPermissions = Get-Mailbox | where {$_.recipientTypeDetails -eq 'sharedmailbox' } | Get-MailboxPermission
```

For the second part I followed this tutorial https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet for creating an MVC app with access to Exchange Online via Outlook REST API and it's working well, to fetch the signed in user's emails from his mailbox.
When I try to to access a shared mailbox the user has *FullAccess* permissions to I receive an access denied exception.

The REST request for this is

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/users/shared@mydomain.com/messages
```

And the wrapped C#-Request is

```
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), GetAccessToken);
client.Context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<Microsoft.OData.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs>((sender, e) => InsertXAnchorMailboxHeader(sender, e, userEmail));
var mailResults = await client.Users["shared@mydomain.com"].Messages.ExecuteAsync();
```

For *userEmail* I've tried the mailbox's email as well as my/current user's email.

Same with the Graph API.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/shared@mydomain.com/messages
```

So far I understand that at the current state of the APIs (!) to access shared mailboxes I need an app token. This might be accomplished by building a service app as described in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

My current flow would be:
 1. Get current users email from SharePoint App via SharePoint CSOM
 2. For this user get the list of mailboxes he has access to via PowerShell (yes, caching..., maybe later)
 3. Using a service app enumerate the unread emails in these mailboxes.

This seems to me like a complete mess of APIs and I have one wish:

Could someone please (!) suggest the proper means to build an MVC app which finds all mailboxes a user has access to and fetches the unread messages

I know that a very similar question has been asked about a year and a half ago ([Accessing all user's mailbox via Office 365 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719228/accessing-all-users-mailbox-via-office-365-rest-api)), but APIs have changed since then, as ([What is the purpose of the new "Read user and shared mail" delegated scope in Azure AD portal for Office 365 Exchange Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616499/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-new-read-user-and-shared-mail-delegated-scope-in-az/38626322?noredirect=1#comment64649553_38626322)) suggests.

Bye
Ben